# How to write something in the Output tab in Visual Studio Code

Tags: output, visual-studio-code

How can I respond to my program in the Output tab of Visual Studio Code?

I am using the [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension. Here is a picture of what I want (lower part, near *"Ausgabe"*):

[image: Down here in Ausgabe]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Output panel doesn't support input. That's one of the reasons why they switched from Output panel to Terminal in version 2 of the Tasks API.

It seems the Code Runner extension [supports running in the Terminal as well](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/91):

```json
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true
```

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio Code (for Mac OS) version 1.49.0, you can input data through the *Output* panel after you make the following change in settings:

1. Click the gear icon in the bottom left corner and select *Settings*:

   [image: see screenshot]
2. Enter "run in terminal" in the search bar:

   [image: see screenshot]
3. Check the box next to "Whether to run code in Integrated Terminal".

> ***Attention:*** Remember to uncheck the box if you want to display the code results on the *Output* tab again.

Answer (score 0):

Yup! you cannot write in the output terminal.

But if you don't want to run that in integrated terminal you can just modify your `code-runner.executorMap` to run that code in a new terminal, which closes after your execution gets finished.

```
"code-runner.executorMap":{
      "c":   "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && gnome-terminal -- bash -c \"./$fileNameWithoutExt\"",  
      "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && gnome-terminal -- bash -c \"./$fileNameWithoutExt\"",  
}
```

this is for `C` & `C++` and similarly you can write it for other languages as well.

here i have added the `gnome-terminal -- bash -c \"./$fileNameWithoutExt\"` part

for details of this command, Click [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974756/how-can-i-open-a-extra-console-and-run-a-program-in-it-with-one-command)! .

Comment: -x was getting deprecated and might get removed in a later version of gnome-terminal, hence I used --